# WPF Live-Regions just for Narrator?

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a textblock (`ContentTextBlock`) with `AutomationProperties.LiveSettings="Assertive"`. I'm just testing and checking how useful this feature is. And... am disappointed so far.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ContentTextBlock.Text += " test";
    var peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(ContentTextBlock);
    if(peer == null)
    {
    peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(ContentTextBlock);
peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
    }
peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
}
```

When using Narrator, this works as advertised. Whenever clicking the button, Narrator announces the TextBlock text ("test" "test test" "test test test")... But when I use NVDA or JAWS, nothing happens, although the screenreader versions are relatively up-to-date. Did they really not add any support for live-regions or am I just missing an important point?

Comment: There is a bug in all currently available versions of JAWS that affects whether or not a live region is spoken in a WPF application. The bug has been fixed. The fix will be avialable in the next update of JAWS 2023 which will be released in February 2023.

Comment: I need the same but for WindowsForms, and I'm still struggling. do you know which event I need to raise on text change? I naïvely thought setting a property would be enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I didn't manage to get live regions to work, I found another workaround:

[Tolk by Davy Kager](https://davykager.com/projects/tolk/)

Tolk is a library which can, among oterrs

- Detect which supported screen reader, if any, is running
- Pass strings to the screen reader's speech engine and braille.
- Also has support for SAPI

To include Tolk in your C# project, download it from the link above, then include `tolk.cs` (from `src/dotnet`) in your project, and place `tolk.dll` (it's found in `bin`) in the folder with your executable (or somewhere in the PATH variable). Make sure that the dll version matches your CPU target (x86/x64). Do the same for the dlls in the lib directory. Then you can use it according to the code found in the examples folder.

PS. Tolk works on Win 7 as well, so that's a bonus. The live-regions of WPF were only supported from Win 8 on.