# Announcing a new window has opened in WPF with Screenreader

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, screen-readers, .net-4.7.2

Upon opening a window, another window opens up unfocused with some relevant information about data protection.

Now I want the windows 10 screen reader to announce that new window.

I tried getting the screen reader to work using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699145/automationproperties-livesetting-not-working-in-wpf-in-net-framework-4-7-1), all worked fine.
When opening a new window, the screen reader automatically reads its title out loud.

In my case, upon opening a specific window another window opens *unfocused*.
The problem is, I cannot find any way to automatically announce the new *unfocused* window when it is being opened.

Using other libraries than the official Microsoft ones, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393782/wpf-live-regions-just-for-narrator), is unfortunately no option in my company.