# How to send message to ScreenReader from WinForms(C#.net) without activating form(taking focusing) -need to send adhoc message

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-readers

My winform app runs in background (showintaskbar false). I need to send alert message to screen reader without activating/focusing my Windows form.
Need to send adhoc messages to screenreader

updated accessibility properties but screen reader announcing only upon activating/focusing

Comment: Generally that's handled with what's called a "live" region. I know how to implement live regions in other technologies but am not familiar with the C# and .Net framework so I only wanted to comment here rather than post an actual answer. I did see this stackoverflow question regarding live regions in C# - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393782/wpf-live-regions-just-for-narrator. Perhaps that might lead you down the right path.